# Missing months with less than 31 days (strtotime)

Tags: php

I want to output the last 13 months, beginning with last month.

my code:

```
for($i=1;$i<=(13);$i++)
{
   echo date("m",strtotime("-".$i." month"));
}
```

It worksfine, but today (31.) it looks like this
07
07
05
05
03
03
01
12
12
10
10
08
07

I am missing the months, that do not have 31 days. How can I fix this?

Comment: Same question repeated regularly every month (with 31 days) on the 31st of the month <sigh />

Comment: Did you read the note about relative months [in the relative formats documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php)?

Comment: If you're  going to take the current date and do month calculations.... don't.... base month calculations off the first day of the month (`1-Aug-2017`)

Comment: thanks for the info page @some programmer dude. could fix it like this: $monat = date("m",strtotime("first day of this month -".$i." month"));

Comment: Check https://3v4l.org/Nokdv

Comment: I would do: https://3v4l.org/rhS69

Answer (score 0):

Works with a DateTime object! ;-)

```
$date = new DateTime('2017-08-31');

for ($i=1; $i<=(13); $i++) {
    $tmpDate = clone $date;
    $tmpDate->modify('last day of -' . $i . ' month');
    echo $tmpDate->format('Y-m-d') . "\n";    
}
```

The trick is to copy the variable so that you can reduce the months times var $i. Using "last day of -x month" always picks the last day of that month.
Reference: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php